# Free Asp.Net ToolTip?`

Tags: asp.net, tooltip

at the moment I use "www.aspnettooltip.com" as my asp.net tooltip.

Feature I need: Complete control how it is displayed (Content-System).

At the moment I can use this:

```
 <ASPNetToolTip:ToolTip ID="ToolTip1" runat="server" ControlToToolTip="imgHelp2">
                        <ToolTipContentTemplate>
                        <div class="divToolTip">
                            Tragen Sie hier bitte "Suchworte" ein mit denen 
                            Sie gefunden werden möchten. Z.B.: Wenn Sie ein Friseur 
                            sind: Haare schneiden, Haare färben, Ihren Firmennamen
                            <br />
                            <br />
                            Sie müssen mindestens 1 und können maximal 6 Suchwörter eingeben.
                            </div>
                        </ToolTipContentTemplate>
                    </ASPNetToolTip:ToolTip>
```

Is there a similiar control which is free?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [JQuery](http://speckyboy.com/2009/09/16/25-useful-jquery-tooltip-plugins-and-tutorials/) .